# Ich bin diese Debatte leid

Tags: grammatical-case

Is "diese Debatte" here Nominativ or Akkusativ? *Leid sein* has the same meaning as satthaben:

> Ich habe diese Debatte satt.

Answer (score 6):

As a rule of thumb you can assume objects to be in either dative or accusative. Some expression require a genitive object. A nominative object<sup>1</sup> is used only rarely as in

> Ich bin ein Mann

Your example sentences need an **accusative object**. If this sentence had been written with a male object, this would have been clearer, since the male nominative and accusative form aren't homonyms.

> Ich bin **diesen Mann** sowas von leid!
> Ich habe **diesen Regen** sowas von satt!

<sup>1</sup> as a technicality, it's not really an object but a predicative nominative.

Comment: Using a noun with a recognisable accusative form only helps only those, who already are aware, that *»leid haben«* and *»satt haben«* need that case. It does not help, if you don't know which case to use. If you have no idea which case is the correct one, *»Ich bin **dieser Mann** sowas von leid!«* and *»Ich bin **diesen Mann** sowas von leid!«* both sound as good or as bad as the other one.

Comment: You missed my point. If you read my example sentence somewhere, you know it needs the accusative form (because diesen Mann is unambigiously the accusative form). Obviously OP struggles, because diese Debatte (nominative) is homonymous to the accusative form.

Comment: Die Frage lautet: *»Steht "diese Debatte" in "Ich habe diese Debatte satt" im Nominativ oder im Akkusativ?«* Du antwortest sinngemäß: *»Ersetze "diese Debatte" durch die richtige Form von "dieser Mann", dann siehst du, welcher Fall passt.«* Genau das funktioniert aber nicht, wenn nicht weiß, ob dort Nominativ oder Dativ hingehört. Wenn man das nicht weißt, klingt *»Ich habe **dieser Mann** satt«* genau so richtig oder falsch wie *»Ich habe **diesen Mann** satt.«* Dein Ansatz ist bei dem ganz konkreten Satz, mit dem der Fragesteller Probleme hat, schlichtweg nicht hilfreich.

Comment: @infinitezero There's no such thing as a "nominative object". The expressions you mean are *predicatives*.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I never argue that way. But whatever.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus I corrected this technicality.

Answer (score -2):

The subject of a sentence is always in nominative case. That other parts of speech are also in nominative case is rare. This only can happen if the verb is a [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(linguistics)). Such verbs are:

- **sein (to be)**

  > Michael ist Lehrer.
  > Michael is a teacher.
- **werden (to become)**

  > Laura wird Mutter.
  > Laura becomes a mother.
- **bleiben (to stay)**

  > Susanne bleibt Autobesitzerin.
  > Susanne stays an owner of a car.

Sometimes also some other verbs can work this way. But if so, then the sentence always expresses that something is equal to something else, or was equal or will be equal. The official term is *Gleichsetzungsnominativ* (*nominative of equalization*)

If the sentence doesn't express such an equalization, then the object is not in nominative case.

It always depends on the verb in which case the object has to be. Only copulas (*to be, to become, to stay* plus some rare constructions with other verbs) need their "object"<sup>1</sup> in nominative case.

There are 51 German verbs that need their object in genitive case (*bedürfen, gedenken, entledigen, ...* full list is [here](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Verben_mit_Genitiv)). All other verbs need dative or accusative case.

1: <sub>Technically an "object" in nominative case, as discussed here, is not really an object. It is a part of the predicate. But still at fist sight it may look like an object.</sub>

Comment: This answer does not even mention that the correct version needs an accusative object. This only happens by deduction (it can't be nominative, so it must be accusative) but technically this answer still allows a dative object.

Comment: But wouldn't this answer imply that, since *ich bin diese Debatte leid* contains *sein*, *diese Debatte* could be a *Gleichsetzungsnominativ* (contrary to fact)?

Comment: @DavidVogt I don't think that the answer implies that. But you made a point. There is the risk of inducing a rule that *sein, werden, haben* always make a *Gleichsetzungsnominativ*. There should be a warning that *Gleichsetzung* means identity here.

Comment: Anonymously downvoting should be disabled.